# How to get command line arguments to a table in Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to pass command lines argument as `Lua$ lua test.lua 5 1 8` and it gives me the out put as 1 2 3 instead of 5 1 8. The code which I tried is given below, The primary objective is, I need to sort those numbers as 1 5 8. I can use "sort" command only for tables.

```
a = {}
for i = 1, #arg do

    table.insert(a, arg[i])

end

for x in pairs(a)do

    print(x)

end
```

what is missing here ? please advice.

Comment: Seems you made a simple typo or did not RTFM :) – `pairs` produces `key, value`, so you're printing the keys (1,2,3), not the values. Fix: `for _, x in pairs( a ) do` …

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to build `arg`. The command-line interpreter `lua` already does that for you.

```
$ cat test.lua
for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
    print(i,v)
end

$ lua test.lua 5 1 8
1   5
2   1
3   8
```

Your code does not work because you're printing only the *keys* in the table (numerical indices in that case), not the *values*.